# Как сделать навигацию (якорь) на переход в пределах одной страницы к определенному TextView

Tags: java, android-studio

Собственно есть длинный код страницы андроид приложения, что - то типа справочника. Страница содержит исключительно много много TextView и ImageView. Как можно кодом реализовать навигацию на странице так, чтобы пользователь, к примеру по нажатию на кнопку вверху страницы сразу переходил путем прокрутки до нужного места - к определенному TextView или ImageView?

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:context="net.ucoz.rfonlinetmb.rfonlinecombine.MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewstrujkaa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Бижутерия Будущего и Цитадели"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewturel40"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:allowUndo="false"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text='   Данная бижутерия добывается с Коробки Драгоценностей Цитадели. Её можно получить за прохождение:'/></TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `scrollView.scrollTo()` либо `smoothScrollTo()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если бы вас не затруднило (я начинающий), то не могли бы вы мне подсказать куда вставлять этот код? В текст кнопки? В xml или class файл?

Comment: в слушатель кнопки

Comment: попробую разобраться, спасибо.